# Wordpress page not displaying CSS

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

The WordPress page is not showing the CSS layouts it should. It shows the border boxes around the text and has an unfamiliar width (700px) when it should be full-width. I have combed the CSS and could not find this number anywhere. It also shows some text that shouldn't be visible ("This site is experiencing technical difficulties").

I have asked all of the developers and people who add content to this page, and none of them have worked on it since the bug.

I have tried editing the CSS and it shows my edits, but the border boxes and width issue persist. I have checked the PHP template files and they are untouched since long before this bug appeared. I even checked the CMS to see if someone inserted code where it doesn't belong and still nothing.

Inspect in Chrome lets me fix it, but I cannot find where in the code to make the permanent change.

`body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #444;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    max-width: 700px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a similar issue in my experience, but maybe try and switching the themes just to force a refresh. Cache might be an issue if there is code somewhere in the pipeline interfering. You mention code in the CMS, do you meant the custom code you can insert in the customization menu of a theme - that could be a good place to check too. Hope it helps!